# Baking Powder in scones

Tags: baking-powder

For scones can I mix cold butter with self raising flour and then add the wet ingredients the next day. This is to save time in the morning?

Answer (score 3):

I do the same as you, Vivien. I find that mixing in the liquids in advance leads to too much gluten development and some outgassing from the baking powder, but that if the butter/flour mixture is kept cold enough it doesn't hurt to mix it the night before.
(Anyway, it takes longer for the oven to heat up than it takes to mix together the remaining ingredients and shape the scones.)

Comment: Outgassing?  You mean you'll get baked pebbles because no rising will happen

Comment: No, nothing that drastic. Modern baking powders don't really do much of the gas production until you heat them up.

Answer (score 2):

I regularly prep scones completely the night before. As in, I make the entire dough, place on a baking sheet, and put in the fridge until morning. So you can even go a step further and add the wet ingredients too the night before to save even more time in the morning.

Comment: You want to make sure you're using 'double acting' baking powder if you do this.  (most of it these days is ... but it someone's trying to stay away from aluminum or only shops at health food stores, it might not be).  Double acting powders produce gas when they're moistened and again when they're heated.